# Определение типа сказуемого в предложении

Tags: глаголы, тип-сказуемого

**И слезы из очей, как звуки, друг за другом льются.**

"Льются" — простое глагольное сказуемое или "друг за другом льются" — составное именное сказуемое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь *друг за другом* — это либо обстоятельство образа действия, либо дополнение. Но никак не сказуемое.

Comment: Это наречное выражение в роли обстоятельства образа действия.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, простое глагольное – "льются".